# Graphical layout with tabs

Tags: android

I am new programmin in Android.
I am trying to use a tab layout with tabhost. I have a question:
I possible to use the graphical layout interface to design the different tab screens or do I have to do it in the XML layout directly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always create GUIs writing XML files by hand, without any graphical tool, so I don't have an answer for your question *but* I have awesome examples for you -- ActionBar Sherlock samples that are **AWESOME** example how to build tab-based apps:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java

Moreover, you can get all these examples on google play store and try them out without building them yourself!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments

I always base my tab-based apps on one of these sample apps. Awesome stuff!

Comment: And whats the difference between ActionBar Sherlock and ViewPagerIndicator (both from the same Author) to create tab pages? I want to use one of these. By the way, you dont go in a mess designing the XML without looking the graphical layout? Does it not take long to design? Thanks

Comment: ABS and VPI are two different "widgets", look here

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s108/sh/dbfb98ff-9dfd-4b9f-b588-7265f6bff10c/0b9075c2766c6539f156c8a25b6ee3a2

basically there are three ways to get tabs:

 1) use ActionBar (or ActionBar Sherlock) tabs
 2) use VPI for tabs
 3) or use good old TabWidget

and don't be afraid of XML files -- they are pretty easy.  just play with them a bit and you will see.